# Как сделать 2 иконки navigationIcon?

Tags: android, разметка

Есть макет, в нем есть уже navigationIcon, переводящая экран на предыдущий.
Как можно добавить к макету еще одну иконку? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content
 android:paddingBottom="16dp"
 app:centeredToolbarStyle="light"
 app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
 app:title="@string/auto_garage"
 tools:subtitle="Обновлено в 11:47" />
```

Comment: Смотря какую иконку и где. Если справа, то делайте через меню. Если где-то ещё, то проще всего убрать Toolbar и сделать его аналого с нуля, ибо тулбар слабо кастомизируется.

Comment: Э...э. "добавить к макету еще одну иконку", не?